# syntax error when calling a function

Tags: python, function, syntax

```
quiz_again = str(input("Enter yes or no")
if quiz_again == "yes":
                 quiz()
```

I am tying to run this on python (idle version 3.4.2)
but I am greeted with syntax error: invalid syntax
and the cursor highlights the ":"
If anyone could explain I would be very appreciative

Comment: missing right parenthesis after `str`, should be `str(input("Enter yes or no"))`.

Comment: Maya, read the *[official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)*, it will help you a lot with these small syntactic mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an indentation issue. If a function `quiz` is defined, try it:

```
quiz_again = str(input("Enter yes or no"))
if quiz_again == "yes":
    quiz()
```

or it's possible to run:

```
quiz_again = str(input("Enter yes or no"))
if quiz_again == "yes": quiz()
```

Comment: Second version is ugly and does not confirm to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). And why do you keep the call to `str` and don't explain that you don't need it because the return value of `input` is already a string?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by Jim, You need to write as:

```
quiz_again = str(input("Enter yes or no"))
```